# Brownie: RPCConnectionError: Able to launch RPC client, but unable to connect

Tags: python, ethereum, blockchain, ganache, brownie

I am new to Brownie. When I followed the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ to study how to use Brownie to deploy blockchain contracts, it gave me an error. `RPCConnectionError: Able to launch RPC client, but unable to connect.`

It seems like the Brownie launched `ganache-cli` and used "http://127.0.0.1:8545" as the URI of the local testing blockchain network, but somehow it doesn't connect to the ganache-cli core, but I tried to start the `ganache-cli` separately, and everything works well. I use Brownie with proxy, but even if I close the proxy it still doesn't connect to the `ganache-cli`. Here are the error codes.

```
(base) D:\OneDrive\xjtu\Labs\blockchain\solidity\bronie_simple_storage>brownie run scripts/deploy.py
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.17.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BronieSimpleStorageProject is the active project.

Launching 'ganache-cli.cmd --port 8545 --gasLimit 12000000 --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --mnemonic brownie'...
Terminating local RPC client...
  File "c:\users\zheng\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "c:\users\zheng\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 44, in main
    network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])
  File "c:\users\zheng\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\main.py", line 50, in connect
    rpc.launch(active["cmd"], **active["cmd_settings"])
  File "c:\users\zheng\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\rpc\__init__.py", line 95, in launch
    raise RPCConnectionError(cmd, self.process, uri)
RPCConnectionError: Able to launch RPC client, but unable to connect.

Command: ganache-cli
URI: http://127.0.0.1:8545
Exit Code: 15
BronieSimpleStorageProject is the active project.
```

Answer (score 2):

ganache by default connects to port 7545, but ganache-cli 8545.

[image]

If you click on settings on the right side, change the port from server tab.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Yilmaz, I tried to change the port number, but it still doesn't work, the issue is still the same. ```RPCConnectionError: Able to launch RPC client, but unable to connect.

Command: ganache-cli
URI: http://127.0.0.1:8545
Exit Code: 15```

Comment: @shledonzheng share your  connection code,pls.

Comment: The ganache-cli launching commands :```Launching 'ganache-cli.cmd --port 8545 --gasLimit 12000000 --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --mnemonic brownie'...
Terminating local RPC client...```

Comment: I've already changed the settings on the  desktop version of ganache, but it doesn't work, I don't understand why the brownie can launch ganache, but it seems like the ganache refused the connection, I ran all this on windows 10

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. But it needs to be clear that one has to make sure that the desktop ganache is running.

Answer (score 0):

```
└─mainnet-fork-dev
    ├─id: mainnet-fork-dev
    ├─cmd: ganache-cli
    ├─cmd_settings: {'accounts': 10, 'fork': '{Insert Alchemy Link here}', 'mnemonic': 'brownie', 'port': 8545}
    └─host: http://127.0.0.1
```

This is What Mine looks like, It may help

Comment: Thanks, but I don't exactly what is the real problem with it, I believe I did everything correctly, but it still shows "unable to connect"

Answer (score 0):

You have to downgrade your nvm version to get it to work.
[Link to related question on GitHub](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-py/discussions/804#discussioncomment-1981426)

You just need to downgrade your node version to 16.13.2 [WSL2 only]:

```
nvm uninstall <current version>

nvm install 16.13.2

nvm use 16.13.2
```

Answer (score 0):

By changing the Ganache port you can solve your problem.
Ganache -> setting -> server -> port number
change to 8545

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue on Brownie 1.19, I noticed that in the error log there was inconsistency in port numbers, the `--server.port` was one and ganache `URL` had another one.

```
Launching 'ganache-cli --chain.vmErrorsOnRPCResponse true --wallet.totalAccounts 10 --fork.url https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/XXX --wallet.mnemonic brownie --server.port 8545 
Command: ganache-cli
URI: http://127.0.0.1:7545
```

The solution that worked, was to modify the network to ensure that the number is consistent on both and matches the computer configuration, like this.

```bash
brownie networks modify mainnet-fork-dev host="http://127.0.0.1:8545" port=8545
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
brownie networks delete mainnet-fork-dev
```

then:

```
brownie networks add development mainnet-fork-dev cmd=ganache-cli host=http://127.0.0.1 fork='https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/put_your_infura_project_id' accounts=10 mnemonic=brownie port=8545
```